# How to parse JSON into data structure

Tags: json, parsing, go

I am trying to parse a JSON of the type

```
"{\"ids\":[\"a\",\"b\"]}"
```

Here is my code:

```
package main

import "fmt"
import "encoding/json"
import "strings"

type Idlist struct {
    id []string `json:"ids"`
}
func main() {
    var val []byte = []byte(`"{\"ids\":[\"a\",\"b\"]}"`)
    jsonBody, _ := strconv.Unquote(string(val))

    var holder Idlist
    if err := json.NewDecoder(strings.NewReader(jsonBody)).Decode(&holder); err!= nil{
        fmt.Print(err)
    }
    fmt.Print(holder)
    fmt.Print(holder.id)
}
```

However, I keep getting output

```
{[]}[]
```

I cannot get the data in the structure.
Where am I going wrong? Here is the playground link: https://play.golang.org/p/82BaUlfrua

Comment: And the next one. Did you take the Go Tour? Did you read the whole documentation of encoding/json?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JSON and dealing with unexported fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11126793/json-and-dealing-with-unexported-fields)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your struct has to look like :

```
type Idlist struct {
    Id []string `json:"ids"`
}
```

Golang assumes that the fields starting with capital case are public. Hence, your fields are not visible to json decoder. For more details please look into this post :
[Why Golang cannot generate json from struct with front lowercase character?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21825322/why-golang-cannot-generate-json-from-struct-with-front-lowercase-character)

Answer (score 0):

This is example how you can resolve your problem: http://play.golang.org/p/id4f4r9tEr

You might need to use `strconv.Unquote` on your string.

And this is probably duplicate: [How to unmarshal an escaped JSON string in Go?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16846553/how-to-unmarsal-escaped-json-string-on-go)

**Resolved**: https://play.golang.org/p/hAShmfDUA_

```
type Idlist struct {
    Id []string `json:"ids"`
}
```

Comment: The example you quote is a starter example. Not that mine is any harder. I am specifically looking for a case where there is an array in the json. Can you please point out the error in my approach. I have attached a go playground link with the code for your convenience. Thanks for your time in advance. Appreciate it.

Comment: Updated the question with your tip and with a new go playground link.

Comment: dude you dont even know anything about golang. Why the hell are you ruining my question ?

Comment: Thank you for you comment, it's true, I don't know Go lang, but I have resolved you problem. Problem is in your structure, you can't use lowercase. https://play.golang.org/p/hAShmfDUA_ Now it works

Comment: Cool thanks man. You are awesome. Sorry for the harsh words. I spent hours on this silly thing and studied the whole lot of parsing.

Comment: No problem, I'm glad I was of any help!