# Unmarshaling a stringified json

Tags: go

I am trying to unmarshal a json with a nested json.

I am using this struct

```
type atomRequest struct {
    Stream string                 `json:"stream"`
    Data   map[string]interface{} `json:"data"`
}
```

if the nested json is stringified, the Unmasrhaling fails and the value is nil

if the byte array that i am marshalling is with a non escape "data"
The "Data" map is being populated correctly.

if the nested json is stringified, I get an empty Data map.

I am looking for a solution to unmarshal the nested data, whether its stringified or not.

The example: this input works:

```
{"stream":"foobar","data":{"errorID":112,"timestamp":1524737466}}
```

This input does not work:

```
{
    "stream": "foo",
    "data": "{\"cd3\":\"514\",\"cd8\":\"none\"}"
}
```

can you help?

thanks

Comment: you stringify an already created json in your javascript remove that.

Comment: take a look at a similar question:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16846553/how-to-unmarshal-an-escaped-json-string-in-go

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [json.RawMessage](https://godoc.org/encoding/json#RawMessage) to capture the varying field:

```
type atomRequest struct {
    Stream  string                 `json:"stream"`
    RawData json.RawMessage        `json:"data"`
    Data    map[string]interface{} `json:"-"`
}
```

Unmarshal the top-level JSON:

```
var req atomRequest
if err := json.Unmarshal(data, &req); err != nil {
    // handle error
}
```

If `data` is a string, unmarshal to remove the extra level of encoding:

```
if len(req.RawData) > 0 && req.RawData[0] == '"' {
    var s string
    if err := json.Unmarshal(req.RawData, &s); err != nil {
        // handle error
    }
    req.RawData = json.RawMessage(s)
}
```

Finally, unmarshal to the `map[string]interface{}`:

```
if err := json.Unmarshal(req.RawData, &req.Data); err != nil {
    // handle error
}
```

[playground example](https://play.golang.org/p/KyNycFse9O3)